# How to stop GameObject duplications when reloading a scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, scene, scene2d

I'm making a game where the player can switch back and forth between levels. I use "DontDestroyOnLoad" to bring my player between them, but whenever I reload a scene, it duplicates the player, as well as everything else I want to keep loaded. Does anyone know any easy fix to this? I'm new to programming so keep it simple please.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to write something like this:

```
public static <TypeName> instance = null;
void Awake() {
  if (instance != null) {
    Destroy(gameObject);
  } else {
    instance = this;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: And for further reading about it, you can search for the "unity singleton pattern". If you make your player a prefab, you can use this pattern and put a copy of the player in every scene so you can easily test and work on each of your levels independently.

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).  Unity is a **CLR Host** whereby it can and will **zap** out the **Primary App Domain** along with all your objects **including singletons** not just during runtime but also whilst using the **Editor**.  See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.